# Tooltip for questions with accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, tooltips

When I hover the mouse pointer over a question having an accepted answer I can see this tooltip:

[image]

Would it not be better to replace the contents of the tooltip with:

> one of the answers was accepted

?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of discourse lately about the "correctness" of an accepted answer.  To clarify, the tooltip over the checkmark says *"The question owner accepted this as the best answer."*  A checkmark on an answer is no guarantee that the answer is correct, only that it was the answer that was most helpful to the OP.

Comment: In any case the tooltip I proposed is more _correct_.

Comment: It appears that the tooltip over the question listing conflicts with the one over the checkmark, as the question listing tooltip contains the word "correct," while the checkmark tooltip does not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no. The accepted answer is the correct answer to this question chosen by the asker.

Comment: It's only the OP's decision if it is correct or not.  We don't actually know if it is correct - all we know is that the OP chose it.

Comment: @Lix "was accepted as the correct answer" to me indicates that is was the OP's decision. If it were phrased "one of the answers is the correct answer" we would have a valid discussion.

Comment: `"correct answer"` indicates to me that the answer that was given is **correct**.  However that's *not always the case...*

Comment: I feel that "was accepted as" provides enough leeway for exactly that case.

Comment: @bar - I don't think that we can expect people to take the tooltip with a pinch of salt.  Correct means only one thing.  `accepted as` does leave some room for interpretation, to fix that you'd have to add *by whom* it was accepted as this is only the opinion of one user...

Comment: @Lix The "by whom" part of things is rather obvious given that there is only one person who can ever accept something. But I'm not opposed to the proposed change. (Though I might drop to the ground, hit the floor with my fists and threaten to rage-quit ;) ) I just don't think it's all the necessary.

Comment: @bar - We forget sometimes how intuitive these sites have become to us.  I could argue that it is not at all obvious that the only person who can accept an answer is the OP... but I won't ;)